# Blackberry Cascades QML Items

Tags: qt, qml, blackberry-playbook

This is question for those who already tried Cascades for Blackberry. Can you use standard QML items, like?

```
Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "lightblue"
}
```

I fail to run this code on a BB10 simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that with Cascades because it does not use Qt QML. Instead, if you want to completely avoid Cascades, you can use [Qt for Playbook](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QNX) wich lets you use Qt QML.

If you choose that your application won't look like the rest of native apps on BB10 though.